# Infinispan with REST server

Tags: rest, caching, infinispan

Hi I am using Infinispan REST server and executing actions such a PUT/GET via client.
Infinispan server war file contails cache configuration file as infini-config.xml having cache name as:

I am successfully able to perform action on the cache defined in Server . But Is there any way by which we can create cache via client itself and connect to it?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Infinispan REST server API does not provide functionality for creating new caches.

See the respective section in documentation:

http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_infinispan_rest_server

> Please note that the REST server only allows interaction with either the default cache (named ___defaultcache) or one of the named caches in the configuration file. This is because the REST server starts the default and pre-defined caches on startup in order to provide consistent behavior.
>
> Creation of new named caches on the fly is not supported.
>
> As a result, if you don’t use a custom configuration file, you’ll only be able to interact with the default cache. To interact with more caches, use a configuration file with the desired named caches.

That is something which we will try to address and solve in future version of Infinispan OData server. The idea is to provide management operations for Infinispan via OData service operations interface.

http://tsykora-tech.blogspot.cz/2014/02/introducing-infinispan-odata-server.html

Comment: In 7.0 we're lifting the limitation by which you can only talk to defined caches. From 7.0, you'll be able to talk to any cache, and when it's not defined specifically in the configuration, it'll be a cache with a copy of the default configuration.